# Numpy: Reduce memory footprint of dot product with random data

Tags: numpy, memory-optimization, dot-product

I have a large numpy array that I am going to take a linear projection of using randomly generated values.

```
>>> input_array.shape
(50, 200000)
>>> random_array = np.random.normal(size=(200000, 300))
>>> output_array = np.dot(input_array, random_array)
```

Unfortunately, `random_array` takes up a lot of memory, and my machine starts swapping. It seems to me that I don't actually need all of `random_array` around at once; in theory, I ought to be able to generate it lazily during the dot product calculation...but I can't figure out how.

How can I reduce the memory footprint of the calculation of `output_array` from `input_array`?

Comment: Is this a simplified example, or are you actually dotting into a large array of normally distributed random numbers? The manner in which `random_array` is generated may be relevant.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky not a simplified example -- this is exactly what I want to do. A method that allows for variation in the generation of `random_array` is a bonus, but not required.

Comment: Having a play around with this, I'm not sure it's possible - `np.dot` needs to know the sizes of all its inputs (as 2D dot product == matrix multiplication). I can't see an (easy) way of using a generator in `np.dot` in any case.

Comment: Not your question, but won't sums of 200k values be *very* normally distributed -- how can you beat the central limit theorem ?

Comment: @Yuushi yeah, it'd take some notion of a lazily calculated array (including metadata such as shape), in which values are not looked up but calculated on the fly. The calculation would probably have to look something like (very hand-wavy) `Rij = random_based_on_seeds(global_rand_seed, i, j)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This obviously isn't the fastest solution, but have you tried:

```
m, inner = input_array.shape
n = 300
out = np.empty((m, n))
for i in xrange(n):
    out[:, i] = np.dot(input_array, np.random.normal(size=inner))
```

Comment: Thanks; don't know why this sensible approach didn't occur to me. :) It's definitely not fast...but in my case, that's a tolerable trade-off.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a situation where using cython could reduce your memory usage. You could generate the random numbers on the fly and accumulate the result as you go. I don't have the time to write and test the full function, but you would definitely want to use `randomkit` (the library that numpy uses under the hood) at the c-level.

You can take a look at some example code I wrote for another application to see how to wrap randomkit:

https://github.com/synapticarbors/pylangevin-integrator/blob/master/cIntegrator.pyx

And also check out how matrix multiplication is implemented in the following paper on cython:

http://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/SciPy2009/paper_2/full_text.pdf

Instead of having both arrays as inputs, just have `input_array` as one, and then in the method, generate small chunks of the random array as you go.

Sorry if it is just a sketch instead of actual code, but hopefully it is enough to get you started.

Comment: This is a great answer -- very useful pointers. I think in the short term, @Bago's workaround will be sufficient, but this is good to have up my sleeve.